# how to send JSON request and get JSON response from server

Tags: java, android, client, android-volley

I have a server to which I need to send a request and get a response.
I am using [volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley) and this is what I have done so far

```
JSONObject request=new JSONObject();
try {
    request.put("ticket_id", ticket_id);
    request.put("start", start);
    request.put("extra", extra);
    request.put("care_category", care_category);
    request.put("k_means", "10");
    request.put("vendor", vendor);
    request.put("earlier_enteries", earlier_enteries);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The response would be something like :

```
{"calculation":5.4444"}
```

How should I rend my request and or if there is any better way to do so ?

Comment: i need to send JSON to the server and get JSON back.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use HTTPs requests (GET and POST). Retrofit and Gson will get it done.

There's a lot of tutorials and examples about it.
See [Retrofit Android Example HTTP GET Request](https://androidclarified.com/retrofit-android-example-http-get-request/)